# Error while trying generate signed bundle: Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithProguard'

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithProguard'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write > java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\appname\android\app\build\intermediates\shrunk_jar\release\minified.jar]
> (Can't read [C:\appname\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\release\118.jar(;;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate jar entry [com/reactnativecommunity/netinfo/a$1.class]))